# iOS Animation is not working after switch to another VC Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have small background animation to change gradient, ex u can see here [animation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nyaoa8u1RJlR3sASqLagbXnUxjtv0BUu/view?usp=sharing)

As you see if i open app first time, animation is working, after the changing View Controller animation is stop.
My code:

```
   func animateGrandient() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 15, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .curveLinear, .repeat], animations: {
        let x = -(self.gradientView.frame.width - self.view.frame.width)
        self.gradientView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: x, y: 0)
    })
}
```

And outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var gradientView: UIImageView!
```

Comment: call your `animateGrandient()` in your viewController viewWillAppear function

Comment: Where do you call your function animateGrandient()?

Comment: I call in viewWillAppear

Comment: add this line  `self.gradientView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity` in the begining of that method

Comment: Thanks, it's working!

Comment: Added as an Answer @Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your `self.gradientView.transform` is changed already before your animation is executed, so you need to reset your `self.gradientView.transform`

**Add this line** `self.gradientView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity` in the beginning  of that method

**fixed code**

```
 func animateGrandient() {
    self.gradientView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 15, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .curveLinear, .repeat], animations: {
        let x = -(self.gradientView.frame.width - self.view.frame.width)
        self.gradientView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: x, y: 0)
    })
}
```